# Create a clickable div inside a clickable article (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am currently trying to put a few clickable div's inside an article tag (HTML5). Now, the problem is that my article is clickable as well, so whenever i try to click my divs it just assumes that i am clicking the article instead. My click listeners are setup in javascript, here is my code:

HTML:

```
<article id='one'>
<div id='somediv' class='up'>Stuff</div>
</article>
```

Of course this is just an example of what im trying to do.

Javascript:

```
    articles = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    articles[i].addEventListener('click',redirect,false);
}

var UpVote = document.querySelectorAll(".up");
for (var i = 0, length = nodeList.length; i < length; i++) {
    UpVote[i].addEventListener('click',UpVote,false);
}
function UpVote(){
    alert(this.id);
}
```

As you can see here, i have 2 loops setting up listeners for all of my article objects and .up class objects. I am sure these work, so do the functions. I haven't posted my redirect function since i am positive it works, i get my redirect.

My CSS:

```
.up{
display:block;
padding-left:3px;
background:rgba(150,195,225,.4);
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(110,110,110,.1);
width:20px;
-webkit-transition: width .3s;
}
```

The article is setup as a block as well.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In your code I see event listeners being attached to article elements and elements that have the class "up" yet in your HTML there are no elements with the up class.

Comment: There are, the somediv is, i just didn't do it. I edited

Answer (score 0):

Look into event bubbling and capturing.  when you click the div, you *are* clicking the article as well, so redirect will fire first and possibly prevent up vote from getting called.